# Open .bmp in Windows Photo Viewer from C++ app

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, mfc

In my program I have a CImage that gets saved to a .bmp file on the hard drive.  How can I have my program automatically open that picture in Windows Photo Viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the default program for that file type/extension to open the file, then you will have to open a shell and tell it to open the program for that file type.

See: [How can you open a file with the program associated with its file extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115574/how-can-you-open-a-file-with-the-program-associated-with-its-file-extension) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You should just run the program, and *probably* give path to the file you want to open through command line parameters. It really depnds on the program you want to run.

On Linux, to start a program, you should use `fork` / `exec` pair. On Windows, you use `CreateProcess`

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but I was also looking for the same and got the answer.
Hope it will be helpful for others also.

```
::ShellExecute(NULL,L"open",_T("rundll32.exe"),_T("shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen picture.bmp"),NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

This will open the picture in Windows Default Photo Viewer.
at the place of `picture.bmp` you need to pass full path of the picture/image like `D:\\picture.bmp`.