# Which APi to use for opening a file with it's associated application

Tags: poco-libraries

I want to open a file using some `POCO API` from my C++ program.
For example i have a file with some extension i.e `.docx`, `.xlsx` which is associated to it's default supported application, let say `.docx` with `MSWord` and `.xlsx` with `MSExcel`.

So is there any API in `POCO` which can launch files with it's associated application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no POCO API for doing this.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115574/how-can-you-open-a-file-with-the-program-associated-with-its-file-extension) for an exemple of the Windows API ShellExecute which you can use.
More complete documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776886(v=vs.85).aspx).